Typescript overlapping but incompatible "enums"
I have two types, that are unions of strings:
The NodeTypes are used in our code to define the type of an viewmodel object
type NodeTypes = 
 | 'PRO_TERM'
 | 'THEME'
 | 'REFERENCE'
 ....

then we have ContentTypes which defines a list of possiblities for the 'type' field from our content coming out of the API
type ContentTypes = 
 | 'TERM'
 | 'THEME'
 | 'REFERENCE'
 ....

the strings I've used are just for example. the list is more than 100 values, each, and they have some overlap, but their use is very distinct.
The problem:
Let's say I have an array of NodeTypes
const someItems: NodeTypes[] = ['PRO_TERM', 'THEME'];
const otherItems: ContentTypes[] = ['TERM', 'THEME', ...];

const test = someItems.includes(otherItems[0]); // <-- TS should throw an error

it happens sometimes that some comparisons are done, where we are accidentally comparing NodeTypes with ContentTypes, and since we use them just as strings, TS doesn't error on that.
So, I'd like to brand each of the possibilities for both of these types, so the mix up is no longer possible.
I have the following:
const nodeTypes = [
 'PRO_TERM',
 'THEME',
 'REFERENCE',
 ....
] as const;

// the union type of all the branded strings
export type NodeType = (typeof nodeTypes)[number] & { __brand: 'NodeType' };

// an enum-like object to use the branded types without having to use 'as' 
export const NODETYPES = Object.fromEntries(nodeTypes.map((type) => [type, type])) as {
  [K in (typeof nodeTypes)[number]]: K & { __brand: 'NodeType' };
};
// maps to 
// NODETYPES: {
//     PRO_TERM: "PRO_TERM" & {
//         __brand: "NodeType";
//     };
//     THEME: "THEME" & {
//         __brand: "NodeType";
//     };
....


creating that same array now became:
const someItems: NodeTypes[] = [NODETYPES.PRO_TERM, NODETYPES.THEME];

since I didn't want to do:
const someItems = ['PRO_TERM', 'THEME'] as NodeTypes[];

because then it would take any string as NodeTypes
after doing the same for ContenTypes, this works in my original intent. However, I did lose type inference which I did have before I started:
type ProTermNode = BasicNode & {
 type: 'PRO_TERM'
}

type ContentNode = ProTermNode | ThemeNode | ....

const node: ContentNode = {...}
if (node.type === 'PRO_TERM') {
 -- node is now inferred as ProTermNode 
}

So now, when
type ProTermNode = BasicNode & {
 type: typeof NODETYPES.PRO_TERM;
}
...
const node: ContentNode = {...}
if (node.type === NODETYPES.PRO_TERM) {
 -- node is still ContentNode
}


This all leads me to believe there must be an easier/simpler way to do this, that perhaps also could fix my type inference issue.
what am I missing? how can this be improved?

I'd love to be able to copy and paste this into my own IDE, but there's just so much pseudocode with ... and -- that I'm fighting to just get to the starting line. Could you provide an easy-to-digest [mre] that lets us work on it immediately and where the issue jumps out at us (e.g., you say // <-- TS should throw an error where it does, in fact, throw an error, so what's the problem)?

How about using actual enums instead of a union type?
From your example, defining:
enum NodeType {
  PRO_TERM = 'PRO_TERM',
  THEME = 'THEME',
  REFERENCE = 'REFERENCE'
}

enum ContentType {
  TERM = 'TERM',
  THEME = 'THEME',
  REFERENCE = 'REFERENCE'
}

This way, if you do:
const someItems: NodeType[] = [NodeType.PRO_TERM, NodeType.THEME];
const otherItems: ContentType[] = [ContentType.THEME, ContentType.TERM];

const test = someItems.includes(otherItems[0]); // This actually errors now.

The test array definition should now display a TS error. The good thing about this is that, despite that technically NodeType.THEME is equal to ContentType.THEME, a comparison between them is still invalid because the enum type is different.
By assigning a value to the enum items you can ensure that NodeType.THEME still resolves to the 'THEME' string so it shouldn't need heavy refactoring.
You can check out this playground for the actual example.

I wanted to avoid TS Enums since they are kinda 'hacky', which is why i went with an object instead, but i might reconsider

I've never heard of enums being "hacky" solutions. What's the reason behind that thought if you don't mind me asking?

hacky was not the right word, but enums turn to objects in JS, so there are some caveats, and they are generally not recommended
